# Async await with map function, promise.all not working

Tags: react-native, promise, expo

I'm building an app using expo and react-native.

I'm trying to load photos from firebase using async await and the map function with Promise.all but all I get back is an array of unresolved promises.

```
renderImages = async () => {
  const images = [];

  if (this.state.images.length > 0) {
    images = this.state.images.map(async (item, index) => {
      const ref = firebase.storage().ref(item);

      var image = await ref.getDownloadURL();

      return (
        <View>
          <Image source={{ uri: image }} />
        </View>
      );
    });

    const imageArray = await Promise.all(images);

    return imageArray || [];
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>STATE.IMAGES.LENGTH is 0</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

all I get back is

```
Promise {
  "_40": 0,
  "_55": null,
  "_65": 0,
  "_72": null,
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a promise array, that looks like a promise. And yes, `renderImages` is an `async function` so of course it returns a promise. Everything appears to be working. Can you please show us the code where you are calling the function, and where you "get back" that result?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I didn't know that `async/await` always returned a `promise`.

I handled the problem by adding this

```
onRenderImages() {
  this.renderImages().then(data => {
     this.setState({ 
         displayImages: data
     })
  })
}
```

Comment: Ah, as suspected.